# Is there a way to add pseudo elements "before"/"after" directly to Chrome's dev tool styles tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Just trying to add those pseudo elements straight in to the "Styles" tab.

Makes testing new pseudo styles a chore, hoping there's an answer to this.

It breaks as soon as I type "`:`". I also tried `<pseudo:before>` to no avail.

Comment: Simply type a selector for the element and add `::after` https://puu.sh/Ey0IZ/8d7df2695d.png

Comment: Ah that's the ticket. Thanks a bunch!